# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll -- Why/How is it referenced in my solution?

Tags: c#, dll, reference

I found tons of posts asking about how to fix when Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll is missing, but I have the exact opposite issue -- it is in my output directory and I have no idea why.

The project in question references another global project within the solution, but I have checked the references and extensions for both projects -- nothing about Microsoft.SqlServer.Types. So, any idea as to why it would be considered a dependency when I rebuild the solution? I go to "Add Reference...", Extensions, and I can see "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" in the list, NOT checked. How do I get rid of this reference?

Background: I just added reporting to my project and was using a data source (.xsd file) in my project. I have since switched to using simple class/object references as the data source so I deleted the XSD data source that used OLEDB to Foxpro DBF files. But I am thinking the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types reference got added at that time and now it won't go away.

The DLL (and regional folders for it) copy to my output directory because I am using the trick where all referenced DLLs get copied and then embedded into the application executable (so that I don't need to use ILMerge or deploy a bunch of DLLs -- the exe is standalone in that regard).

How do I find out where this reference is still sticking and get rid of it?

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, it looks like Microsoft.SqlServer.Types is required by Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common. So, just adding reporting to my app brings in a lot of stuff... (well, not really that much, size-wise...)

Comment: It seems that VS2015 automatically includes this assembly (along with international resource files) in the build output folder, whereas VS2013 did not. I only started seeing this file in the output folder after upgrading the project from VS2013 to VS2015. In my case, I would prefer not to have these files included, since I already went through the trouble of installing the Sql Server types separately on my target server.